# php security function to filter our malicious code is stripping out legit characters

Tags: php, security, function

I have a security function which is part of a script. It's supposed to filter out malicious code from being executed in an input form. It works without a problem with normal characters from A-Z, but it rejects inputs with characters such as á, ñ, ö, etc.

What can I do so that form inputs with these characters are not rejected? Here is the function:

```
function add_special_chars($string, $no_quotes = FALSE)
{
  $patterns = array(
      "/(?i)javascript:.+>/",
      "/(?i)vbscript:.+>/",
      "/(?i)<img.+onload.+>/",
      "/(?i)<body.+onload.+>/",
      "/(?i)<layer.+src.+>/", 
      "/(?i)<meta.+>/", 
      "/(?i)<style.+import.+>/",
      "/(?i)<style.+url.+>/"
  );


    $string = str_ireplace("&amp;","&",$string);

    if (!$no_quotes) $string = str_ireplace("&#039;","'",$string);

    $string = str_ireplace('&quot;','"',$string);
    $string = str_ireplace('&lt;','<',$string);
    $string = str_ireplace('&gt;','>',$string);
    $string = str_ireplace('&nbsp;',' ',$string);

  foreach ($patterns as $pattern)
  {
     if(preg_match($pattern, $string))
     {
        $string = strip_tags($string);
     }
  }      



  $string = preg_replace('#(&\#*\w+)[\x00-\x20]+;#u', "$1;", $string);
  $string = preg_replace('#(&\#x*)([0-9A-F]+);*#iu', "$1$2;", $string);

  $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, LANG_CODEPAGE);

  $string = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+[\x00-\x20\"\'\/])(on|xmlns)[^>]*>#iUu', "$1>", $string);

  $string = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*=[\x00-\x20\/]*([\`\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*j[\x00-\x20]*a[\x00-\x20]*v[\x00-\x20]*a[\x00-\x20]*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:#iUu', '$1=$2nojavascript...', $string);
  $string = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*=[\x00-\x20\/]*([\`\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*v[\x00-\x20]*b[\x00-\x20]*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:#iUu', '$1=$2novbscript...', $string);
  $string = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*=[\x00-\x20\/]*([\`\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*-moz-binding[\x00-\x20]*:#Uu', '$1=$2nomozbinding...', $string);
  $string = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*=[\x00-\x20\/]*([\`\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*data[\x00-\x20]*:#Uu', '$1=$2nodata...', $string);

  $string = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+[\x00-\x20\"\'\/])style[^>]*>#iUu', "$1>", $string);

  $string = preg_replace('#</*\w+:\w[^>]*>#i', "", $string);

  do
  {
     $original_string = $string;
     $string = preg_replace('#</*(applet|meta|xml|blink|link|embed|object|iframe|frame|frameset|ilayer|layer|bgsound|title|base)[^>]*>#i', "", $string);
  }
  while ($original_string != $string);   

    return $string;
}
```

UPDATE: I found that the following line seems to be causing the problem, but not sure why:

```
 $string = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+[\x00-\x20\"\'\/])style[^>]*>#iUu', "$1>", $string);
```

Comment: Your function is written the wrong way around. You should instead _allow_ only good characters instead of _removing_ bad characters.

Comment: don't mess with security - this is not a place to re-invent the wheel. If this is just for learning purposes, fine, but if this is anything that might go live - use a known library or internal language function.

Comment: I've never seen the character encoding LANG_CODEPAGE, but my first guess is that's the line which strips your desired UTF-8 characters. Try using UTF-8 instead of LANG_CODEPAGE as the last arg to html_entity_decode() and see if they make it through that way. Although I have to agree with previous comments, there are broader design problems with this function that you might want to consider, too.

Comment: You might be better served with HTMLPurifier. It's not clear which regex character class might strip accented characters. But it's possibly the `#u` UTF-8 modifier, if you actually receive Latin1 or so.

Comment: The LANG_CODEPAGE is actually a variable which is iso-8859-1 in the configuration file. I tried changing it to UTF-8 and then the form works, but it stores the "ñ" in the database as "Ã±" so that creates another problem. I didn't write the script, I'm just the dummy trying to fix it :)

Comment: I tracked the problem down further and it's this line that is stripping out the accented characters:  $string = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+[\x00-\x20\"\'\/])style[^>]*>#iUu', "$1>", $string);

Comment: Maybe I'm better off asking the specific replacement line in a separate post. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bad idea.   The worst part of your function is the `htmlentity_decode()` half way though,  which undermines the first 1/2 of this function entirely.   The attacker can just encode the quote marks and brackets, and you'll just build the payload for the attacker.  `strip_tags()` is a joke, and is not a good way to protect against XSS.  The main problem with this function is that it is far too simple.  [HTMLPurifer](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is made up of **thousands** of regular expressions and it does a much better job,  but it isn't perfect.

You are hardly addressing the most common forms of XSS.  [XSS is an output problem](https://sitewat.ch/en/Blog/5),  you can't expect to pass all input though some magical function and assume its safe.  XSS depends on **how it is used**.

Without actually running your code i think something like this would bypass it:

```
<a href='jav&#x41%3b&#x53%3bcript&#x3a%3balert(1)'>so very broken</a>
```

or maybe even something more simplistic:

```
<img src=x onerror=alert(1) />
```

Like I said this is a **gross oversimplification** of a extremely complex problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm better off asking the specific replacement line in a separate post. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user1227914  Honestly in order for this method to work as intended it needs to be a few thousand lines longer.